# Change Cookie not working

Tags: c#, cookies, internet-explorer-8

I am using web browser and trying to change the cookies but the cookie remains null i donot know why

any idea why it does not changes.i tried to monitor but observed that the method `InternetSetCookie` is not changing it,but the page that was navigated to renders and page changes cookie not my method

```
  [DllImport("wininet.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrlName, string lbszCookieName, string lpszCookieData);
InternetSetCookie(textBox1.Text, null, "123");  
             webBrowser1.Navigate(textBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass null for the cookie name.  And *do* pay attention to the return value, you should get false here because of the invalid name.  Use `throw new Win32Exception()` so an error doesn't go unnoticed.

Comment: Don't pass null for the cookie name can i get the possible names that i can replace.There are some certain ir depends in website that is storing cookie

Comment: The data area passed to a system call is too small result of placing Exception